# C# getKey from a IDictionary by Value - Values can be repeated

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have this `public static IDictionary<int, int> dictionaryLIndex;`

that after filling it and printing it gives me this:

```
key = 0, value = 18
key = 1, value = 2
key = 2, value = 1
key = 3, value = 18
key = 4, value = 3
```

This Dictionary is being created by using:

`dictionaryLIndex= ELWIndex.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);`

ELWIndex is a `IList<KeyValuePair<int,int>>` So the Key i print from the dictionary is actually the index of a list.

Clarifying that, I need to get the key of the dict based on a value. The thing here is that this values can be repeted so how can i accomplish this? Taking in count that this proccess can be called from time to time.

The final goal is to get that key (index from a list) and search in another list for that position and do something to that index.

Just one thought that just came to me. After getting the first value with that key, can i delete that key-value pair from the dict all together?? So the next time there will be just one key with that value...

So how can i get the key from a value given? and, is this last second thought viable?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Why do you think that *"Key i print from the dictionary is actually the index of a list."*? You are using keys from list, not indexes

Comment: yes, you are right @SergeyBerezovskiy.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but try doing it "by hand". All you have is the value `18`. What would your manual process be to know if the key you want is `0` or `3`? -- it's simply too little information. Do you at least know if it is "the first time" you're looking for `18` or "the second time"?

Comment: @Corak based well that is the main issue. Right now there is no difference on which one is getting first. the problem here is to know how to get the key from a value. I am sorry if i threw that second thought there and i confused everyone. No actually i do not know if is the first time or the second time

Comment: @NachoMiguel - Well, if you just want *any* key for a specific value, look at the answer of dasblinkenlight which is O(n). If you do that a lot, you could create an ILookup like: `var lookup = dictionaryLIndex.ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);` and then check `if (lookup.Contains(18)) { var key = lookup[18].First(); /* use key */ }` which should be O(1).

Comment: "The thing here is that this values can be repeted so how can i accomplish this?" What do you want to do about this fact? Pick an arbitrary key, return an `IEnumerable<T>` of all of the matches? Pick one based on some further criteria?

Comment: There's a reason we get values based on keys, not the other way around, and this is it. The key is unique, the value is not, there really is no way to know which key you want based on what you gave, or where else the key matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FirstOrDefault` to get the first key-value pair from a dictionary based on a value:

```
var search = 18;
var kvp = dictionaryLIndex
    .Where(p => p.Value == search)
    .Cast<KeyValuePair<int,int>?>()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If `kvp` is `null`, search value is not in the dictionary.

If `kvp` is not `null`, use `kvp.Key` to find the key. You can later delete that key from `dictionaryLIndex`.

```
if (kvp.HasValue) {
    var key = kvp.Value.Key;
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}", key);
}
```

**Note:** A cast to nullable `KeyValuePair<int,int>?` is necessary because `KeyValuePair<int,int>` is a value type, and both its members are value types as well.

Comment: i am trying to get the key from kvp (kvp.key) but that is not working, i tried casting it but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understood you correctly and you are trying to create another dictionary that does not contain duplicate values, I think that this could work for you:

```
Dictionary<int, int> noDuplicates = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (var item in dictionaryLIndex)
{
    if (!noDuplicates.ContainsValue(item.Value))
    {
        noDuplicates.Add(item.Key,item.Value);
    }
}
```